# outputing array values specific

Tags: c#, arrays

i am working on a very specific problem. this program prompts the user for a number between 1-10000000 and then another number 1-10000. the first number is how many random numbers and the second is what the max those numbers can be is. im trying to print  the result on user prompt and print if user wants to print results and the result are number of primes. first problem is i cannot get the program to respond to the user pushing 1 or 0 to print results. second is i cannot get the number of primes that were created to print as a resut

```
namespace PRIMECON
{
    class PRIMECON
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            //creates stopwatch
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

            //creates randoms
            Random rnd = new Random();

            //starts the stopwatch
            watch.Start();

            //gets number from 1 to 10 million
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 10,000,000");

            bool checkn;
            int number; //input

            checkn = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);

            //gets number from 1 to 10 thousand
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 10,000");

            bool checkr;
            int range; //range of values from 0 to r

            checkr = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out range);

            if (checkn == true && checkr == true && number > 0 && number <= 10000000 && range > 0 && range <= 10000)
            {
                //array
                int arraySize = 0;
                //int[] array = new int[range];

                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    int randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, range);
                    bool primeNumber = PRIMELIB.PRIMELIB.IsItPrime(randomNumber); //calls library method

                    if (primeNumber == true)
                        arraySize++; //adds to the array for each prime number
                    //array[i] = randomNumber;
                    //prints numbers
                    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " " + randomNumber.ToString() + " " + primeNumber.ToString()); // prints index, number, true/false
                }
                //int[] array = new int[arraysize];
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("\nElapsed Time = " + watch.Elapsed.ToString());

                int exit = 1;

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("would you like to print results? 0-no 1-yes");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    int rangeHigh;
                    int rangeLow;
                    bool high = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rangeHigh);
                    bool low = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rangeLow);

                    if (high == true && low == true)
                    {
                        for (int i = rangeLow; i < rangeHigh; i++)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine( i + ". " + array[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (exit != 0);
            }
            else if (checkn == false || number > 10000000 || number < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("First number was not valid");
            else if (checkr == false || range > 10000000 || range < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Range was not valid");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("entry not valid");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you including the library with using at the top of your file and did you add reference?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I can post an answer about your "cannot get the program to respond to the user pushing 1 or 0 to print results" issue. Since your are reading the console line within the do/while loop you can use the int.Parse function then put the inner part of the while loop in an if statement so it will only execute if the user picked yes. The loop will now become this:

```
int exit = 1;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("would you like to print results? 0-no 1-yes");
    exit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (1 == exit)
    {
        int rangeHigh;
        int rangeLow;
        bool high = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rangeHigh);
        bool low = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rangeLow);
        if (high == true && low == true)
        {
            for (int i = rangeLow; i < rangeHigh; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine( i + ". " + array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
while (exit != 0);
```

For your library issue with not being able to get the number of primes that were created my only suggestion is to check your references to see if you include it, and if you added the using for it at the top of your code. I have not used custom libraries in c#, but searching around in google on how to use libraries in c# will be your best bet.